# Different levels of politeness to ask for help

Tags: politesse

> 1. **M’aiderez-vous** à trouver un moyen de le faire ? {**Will you** help me?}
> 2. **M’aideriez-vous** à trouver un moyen de le faire ? {**Would you** help me?}
> 3. **Aidez-moi** à trouver un moyen de le faire ? {**Please** help me.}
> 4. **Veuillez m’aider** à trouver un moyen de le faire ? {**Would you please** help me?}

I wonder how these four expressions rank in terms of politeness levels. I mean, from the least polite to the most polite.

Do my English translations correctly reflect the different levels of politeness suggested in the French sentences?

Comment: Parmi les formules les plus polies : ***Pourriez-vous** m'aider à...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 4) "veuillez m'aider" is an imperative, like (3) but with a pedantic tone, so it is not polite at all.
- 3) "aidez-moi" is an imperative without the pedantic tone, equivalent to "help me.". It's not particularly polite.
- 1) "m'aiderez-vous" is equivalent to "will you help me?".
- 2) "m'aideriez-vous" is equivalent to "would you help me?".

The equivalent to "please, help me" is "s'il vous plait, aidez-moi." It is quite the same level of politeness as (2) but is more used in spoken language, whereas (2) and (1) are rarely found outside written French and sound more literary.